How do I add MySQL Connector/J to a Gradle IntelliJ project?
I'm trying to create a Gradle project using IntelliJ 2024.3 and MySQL Connector/J 8.4.0, but every attempt (save one) fails at runtime with a ClassNotFound exception.
I attempted to follow the instructions from this old StackOverflow post to add Connector/J via maven: under the File menu, choose Project Structure.  Under Platform Settings > Libraries in the left sidebar, click the + icon and select "From Maven..."  Enter "com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.4.0"; leave the "Download to" checkbox unselected, and hit OK.  In the resulting "Choose Modules" dialog, select all 3 (jdbctest, jdbctest.main, jdbctest.test), and hit OK.  Hit OK in the Project Structure dialog.
Define the following class in src/main/java:
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      DriverManager.getConnection(
        String.format(
          "jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s?useSSL=false",
          "localhost",
          3306,
          "BlogApplication"
        ),
        "root",
        "my-database-password"
      );
      System.out.println("It worked!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}


Right-click on JDBCTest inside src/main/java and select "Run JDBCTest.main()".  I expect this to print "It worked!" and terminate, but it consistently fails with the message "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BlogApplication?useSSL=false".
I managed to get this to work once through random flailing, but I'm trying to reproduce, and I'm not able to do so.
I can run the program above, built from IntelliJ, from the command line with no difficulty:
java -cp ~/path/to/mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar:build/classes/java/main JDBCTest

prints "It worked!" and exits with code 0.
I can only assume I'm overlooking something trivial.  What is it?  Do I need to ditch gradle & use maven?

You can add a dependency on the Maven artifact. In Gradle, you would have something like implementation("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:<version>") within the dependencies block (replace <version> with the desired version).
